# How do I include layout attribute before parent layout?

Tags: android, android-xml

I am using One Activity and others are fragments. My parent layout is cardview and I want to add another layout at the top the using include layout tag. Below I posted output images and code:.

This is my card Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/cardview"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
android:elevation="0dp">
<include layout="@layout/edit_text"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:textColor="#4928ef"
    android:textStyle="italic"/>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

And this is my common layout, which I have to include in above card layout

**edit_text.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="GO"
    android:id="@+id/go"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    />
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Quick Search"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Output

[Click here to display output of above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1VKY.png)

I tried to change cardview parent to LinearLayout and cardview as child but I don't know why list item (textview) the first one only displays and others are ignored. I am trying to make layout like below:

[Click here to see what I expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2Z5Z.png)

Answer (score 0):

remove

```
<include layout="@layout/edit_text"/>
```

from your cardView layout, because cardView should have only one ChildView.
so as i understand, you want to use search bar on top.
so here is my implementation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.tiikr.OverlayActivity">

    <include layout="@layout/edit_text"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</LinearLayout>
```

so here i use LinearLayout as a parent of the view, and on top is your search bar layout, and down is the listView wich you need to populate in the code with your cardview layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/cardview"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
android:elevation="0dp">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:textColor="#4928ef"
    android:textStyle="italic"/>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**See above code with RecyclerView**

Comment: No, I can't use ListView, I am already using recyclerview with cardview. Anyway thanks for the help.. I will play in a code while..

Comment: It is easy, just change the ListView to RecyclerView, and it should work

Answer (score 0):

Use only 1 child in `cardView`

Try this

**main.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/cardview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include layout="@layout/edit_text" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:text="Textview"
            android:textColor="#4928ef"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textStyle="italic" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

and **edit_text.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="GO"
        android:id="@+id/go"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Quick Search"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: This will give this]

Adjust background using `android:background="@drawable/background"`

Comment: Not working show four edittext. I think the problem is with fragment

Comment: @Queendevelopers As you are using `main.xml` as row of each item of `RecyclerView` that's why it is showing 4 `editText`

Comment: Yes absolutely... but I have no other option to use  another layout as main?  I am using fragment in this case and to show these content i need to replace previous activity content with main.xml? This issue is painning..