# Unable to display string-array to custom Recycler View?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-xml

As I see many tutorials on website, most of they define the String data in java like String[] data={"value","value2',"value3"};  but its not the correct way in real time application i guess. In my app I will be using other languages too so I need to define in the xml. No matter i call them using below code:

onCreateView

```
 String[] eArray=getActivity().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.english_names);
```

and call them like

```
 names.add(new Name(eArray));
```

but when i hover mouse on eArray it shows error like Name (java.lang.String) in Name cannot be applied to (java.lang.String[])

and I know I must pass other value to array but how? I change error line and it keeps showing other and other. I google many tuts site but all of them are defining string pragmatically.

I made  a custom recyclerview, Below is a code of it

cardview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/cardview"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
android:elevation="0dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:textColor="#4928ef"
    android:textStyle="italic"/>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

recyclerview.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
android:background="@drawable/big_img_boy_wp">
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/rv">
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</LinearLayout>
```

cardview.java

```
public class cardView extends Fragment {
TextView textView;
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_view,container,false);
    textView= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
   // Typeface typeface=Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(),"fonts/Cavorting.otf");
  //  textView.setTypeface(typeface);
    return  view;

}
}
```

Name.java

```
public class Name {
String textView;
Name(String textView){
    this.textView=textView;
}
}
```

recycler.java

```
public class Recycler extends Fragment {
private List<Name> names;
RecyclerView rv;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.recyclerview,container,false);
    rv= (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rv);
    String[] eArray=getActivity().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.english_names);
    LinearLayoutManager llm=new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    rv.setLayoutManager(llm);
    rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
    initializeData();
    initializeAdapter();
    return view;
}
private void initializeAdapter() {
 rvadapter adapter=new rvadapter(names);
    rv.setAdapter(adapter);
}

public void initializeData() {
    names=new ArrayList<>();
    names.add(new Name("Anish"));
    names.add(new Name(eArray));
}

}
```

rvadapter.java

```
public class rvadapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<rvadapter.NameViewHolder> {
public static  class NameViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    CardView cv;
    TextView textView;

    public NameViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        cv= (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardview);
        textView= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);

    }
}
List<Name> names;
public rvadapter(List<Name> names) {
    this.names=names;


}

@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}

@Override
public NameViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_view,parent,false);
    NameViewHolder nvh=new NameViewHolder(v);
    return nvh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(NameViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.textView.setText(names.get(position).textView);

}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return names.size();
}
}
```

Please also take a look at my cardview.java where i put commented, that font also doesn't change. I put font inside assets then font folder. This is my second question in stackoverflow but my first question was as not answered correctly, if you can please take a look at that to[Click here  to to look by another problem too.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38941017/how-do-i-include-layout-attribute-before-parent-layout)  Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        for (int i = 0; i < eArray.length; i++) {
            names.add(new Name(eArray[i]));
        }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, It Worked!! :)  please look down I am also not able to change  font as well as look my another question which hasn't been solved yet..